# how to control Audio output on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio-streaming

I have connected HDMI screen to my Win7 laptop. I want to listen to the music through my headphones. Whenever HDMI is on the Audio goes also to the HDMI screen. Can not find a way to control where the audio should go. Is there a simple way to control it in Windows7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the speaker icon in the bottom right of the screen, choose "Playback Devices", choose the playback device you want and rightclick and designate as standard/default.

Addendum:
The above solution works well enough if you switch audio output devices once in a while, but if you find yourself often having to switch between headphones and speakers then that method gets tedious. If you're on a windows 7 computer (might work on W8 too) then someone has developed a commandline tool utilizing undocumented MS API to switch playback devices, the sourcecode and a download link to the tool can be found here:
http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/